# Scaling a window and Component

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

Hi i'm working on a electron project using HTML javascript and css and there is any way we can scale the window with the components insinde, So when you are on Window the window and the components inside (Pictures,Text) looks the same as on a mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean can you set a webpage up so when its shrinks the content shrinks inside, You can try to use percentages when declaring the width and height of objects in your CSS

If you mean can you set up a webpage so it loads the exact same on mac as it does on windows yes you can I would highly recommend making sure all your code is correct then using a validator to make sure your website will run on all Operating systems

I recommend this website: [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, (Sorry if the question was unclear english is not my native langague) I just want to know something, is using percentages mean that when you resize the window it will automatically adjuste it to make it looks the same as a fullscreen window ?

Comment: Yes if its say 70% and you scale the window down it scales to 70% of the windowed view